# ComboBox has its old value after Clear()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have two comboBox `cb_Brand` and `cb_Model` on a winForm.

`cb_Model` populates values on brand Select.
the problem is: if we select the brand any and select the any model under that brand, `cb_Model` does not loose the value of previous model selected. 
for example: If we select the brand Audi and model A3
and the select the Brand Ford, when I click on `cb_Model` to select the model, it displayed the A3 as selected model, but still other models in list are belong to ford.

my code is:

```
private void cb_Brand_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Clear Current Data
    cb_Model.Text = "";
    cb_Model.Items.Clear();

    CarModel _carmodel = new CarModel ();

    // Get Selected Car Brnad
    int CarBrandID = _carmodel .GetCarBrandID(cb_Brand.Text);

    //Enable choice of Model
    SortedList<int, Model> colM;

    colM = Model.ReadModel(CarBrandID);

    cb_Model.DisplayMember = "ModelText";
    foreach (Model objM in colM.Values)
    {
        cb_Model.Items.Add(objM);
    }
}
```

Any Idea Please..
Thanks

---

unable to find the reason but sorted out with a temp fix:

```
private void cb_Model_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cb_Model.Text = "";
}
```

Thanks a lot guys
cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of adding the items manually like this:

```
foreach (Model objM in colM.Values)
{
    cb_Model.Items.Add(objM);
}
```

Let .NET take care of it for you and replace it with this:

```
cb_Model.DataSource = colMValues;
```

Which will bind the data to the list and refreshes the comboboxes items automatcially when a data source is set.

You will also not need these lines anymore:

```
// Clear Current Data
cb_Model.Text = "";
cb_Model.Items.Clear();
```

Have a read of this for more info on binding lists (and other data sources) to ComboBoxes:

[How to: Bind a Windows Forms ComboBox or ListBox Control to Data (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w67sdsex.aspx)

Comment: smart solution, but does not make any difference for me. Actually the only populates when I click on 'cb_Model' to select the model. It seems its keeping that value somewhere in memory.

Answer (score 6):

@w69rdy suggests an excellent solution.

The reason cb_Model did not change it's *`value`* is because you never changed the value. cb_Model.Items.Clear() does not change the selected index; only the items are removed from the combo box.

Using the code sample provided in your question:

```
// Clear Current Data
cb_Model.Text = "";
cb_Model.Items.Clear();
cb_Model.SelectedIndex = -1;    // would effectively clear the previously selected value.
```

Comment: I already tried 'cb_Model.SelectedIndex = -1;', but no difference.

Comment: @Scorpion: another option, I believe, is to set `SelectedItem = null`

Comment: @Scorpion: there is something else that is keeping the value from clearing. Any of the suggestions here would work ... as maephisto says, it works for him - so I would suggest that there is something you are missing   ;)

Comment: Could not find the reason but found a temp fix. `        private void cb_Model_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cb_Model.Text = "";
        }`

Answer (score 3):

i had same problem now and Combobox's ResetText method solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
combobox.ResetText();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your example. For me it worked as it should have.
You could try setting the cb_model.SelectedText to "" or SelectedItem to null

Comment: does not make any difference, I'm also amazed, I have similar controls on search form and they are working fine... it only happening on edit form.

Comment: did you made sure that Model.ReadModel(CarBrandID) returns only the ford models ?

Answer (score 0):

I found that keeping the scope of the data source near the loading of the combo box worked for me.  I had a datatable with class level scope and it did not clear but then I brought it into function level scope and had it clear after the load and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem,tried cmb.resettext it clears text but not value.In my load form I have the below code: 
`Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT stud_id,name FROM student_details WHERE stud_id NOT IN (SELECT stud_id FROM student_details WHERE hostel_id!=0)", sqlcont.Conn)
            Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Dim dat As New DataTable
            Dim j As Integer
            For j = 0 To dat.Rows.Count - 1
                dr.Read()
            Next
            dat.Load(dr)
            cmbstud.DisplayMember = "name"
            cmbstud.ValueMember = "stud_id"
            cmbstud.DataSource = New BindingSource(dat, Nothing)
            dr.Close()` 
In my btnhostel click event I have the below code:
frmallocateHostel_Load(Nothing, Nothing)
this I put in attempt to reload my dataset and thus my comboboxes.Using cmbstud.resettext simply clears the text not the value.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem then I used

```
combobox1.SelectedIndex=-1
```

and it works.