# Combobox Showing Old Database Values

Tags: c#, combobox

I retrived values by the use of `SqlCommand` and `SqlReader` from column and stored in `List<String>` and the added to **ComboBox(Type:DropDownList)** but Eventhough i have deleted Some of this values from database Combobox is still showing it.

I am clearing items befor allocating by

```
mycombobox.Items.Clear();
```

It looks as it is not affected by values I retrive every time when the Form gets Loaded.

```
    SqlDataReader rdr1 = null;
    SqlConnection con1 = null;
    SqlCommand cmd1 = null;
 try
            {
               List<string> namesCollection=new List<string>();

                // Open connection to the database
                string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=MyPC-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DryDB;Integrated Security=True";
                con1 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

                con1.Open();

                cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT PName from MASTER order by PName";
                cmd1.Connection = con1;

                rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

                namesCollection.Add("Select");


                if (rdr1.Read()==true)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        namesCollection.Add("" + rdr1[0].ToString());
                    } while (rdr1.Read()) ;
                }
                else
                {

                }
                foreach(string pname in namesCollection)
                cb.Items.Add(pname);

                namesCollection.Clear();

                cb.SelectedIndex =0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { 
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                if (rdr1 != null)
                    rdr1.Close();

                if (con1.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    con1.Close();
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, after deletion of some of the values form database, re-populate the Combox. If you can show some code, we can help you where to and how to.

Comment: You have to rebind combo box to get latest values from db..

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the code you have posted and check that is being executed everytime the form loads. Also double check that you're deleting/selecting from the same database as I can see from your code that you hardcoded the connection string.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `namesCollection` list? you can add the values directly to the `BomboBox`

Comment: @AskThakare Can ya provide your code for deletion?

Comment: @AskThakare Did you rebind your ComboBox or reload the form after you have deleted some records from your database?

Comment: @AskThakare So even if you delete some data from database and reload the form, your old data still exists in ComboBox?

Comment: @AskThakare I have posted an answer. Try using the `DataSource` property of the `Combobox` instead of adding the items in the `foreach`. Let me know if it works

Comment: Yeah you should try @juanreyesv solution first. ComboBox `DataSource` property can handle that for you instead of adding the items one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DataSource` property of the `Combobox` instead of the adding the items one by one. So your code will be something like the following:

```
SqlDataReader rdr1 = null;
SqlConnection con1 = null;
SqlCommand cmd1 = null;
try
        {
           List<string> namesCollection = new List<string>();

            // Open connection to the database
            string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=MyPC-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DryDB;Integrated Security=True";
            con1 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

            con1.Open();

            cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT PName from MASTER order by PName";
            cmd1.Connection = con1;

            rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            namesCollection.Add("Select");


            if (rdr1.Read()==true)
            {
                do
                {
                    namesCollection.Add("" + rdr1[0].ToString());
                } while (rdr1.Read()) ;
            }
            else
            {

            }
            //Replace this part...
            //foreach(string pname in namesCollection)
            //cb.Items.Add(pname);

            //With this...
            cb.DataSource = namesCollection;


            cb.SelectedIndex =0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            if (rdr1 != null)
                rdr1.Close();

            if (con1.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                con1.Close();
        }
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306719/combobox-has-its-old-value-after-clear?rq=1)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the code to populate the `ComboBox` is placed in the `populate_cb()` method

```
private void populate_cb(){
    cb.Items.Clear();
    SqlDataReader rdr1 = null;
    SqlConnection con1 = null;
    SqlCommand cmd1 = null;
    try
    {
        // Open connection to the database
        string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=MyPC-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DryDB;Integrated Security=True";
        con1 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        con1.Open();

        cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT PName from MASTER order by PName";
        cmd1.Connection = con1;

        rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        cb.Items.Add("Select");
        while(rdr1.Read())
        {
            cb.Items.Add(rdr1[0].ToString());
        }
        cb.SelectedIndex =0;
        con1.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        // handle exception
    }
}//end of populate_cb()
```

Call `populate_cb()` method form `form_load()` and

Call from the place **after the deletion process**

You need to make sure your deletion process really deletes the records from database!