# Refresh ComboBox in Windows form with datasource retains value even when datasource is empty

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes, cmbstud and cmbhostel. They are filled from the database by binding the datasource to the datatable. As I update, the cmbstud updates accordingly. When I update the last record the datatable empties, but cmbstud still retains the value. Cmbhostel data is bound to change index of cmbstud.

In the form load event I have this code:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT stud_id,name FROM student_details WHERE stud_id NOT IN (SELECT stud_id FROM student_details WHERE hostel_id!=0)", sqlcont.Conn)
Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
Dim dat As New DataTable
Dim j As Integer
For j = 0 To dat.Rows.Count - 1
    dr.Read()
Next
dat.Load(dr)
cmbstud.DisplayMember = "name"
cmbstud.ValueMember = "stud_id"
cmbstud.DataSource = New BindingSource(dat, Nothing)
dr.Close()
sqlcont.Conn.Close()
```

In my btnhostel for updating I have the following queries implemented and the following code to reload the form to refresh my datasources:

```
"UPDATE hostel SET in_use=in_use+1 WHERE hostel_id=@hostid"
"UPDATE student_details SET hostel_id=@hostid where stud_id=@stud_id"
frmallocateHostel_Load(Nothing, Nothing)
```

Cmbstud index change evnt code:

```
Dim sqcm5 As New SqlCommand("Select hostel.hostel_id,hostel.hostel_name From hostel Inner Join student_details On student_details.gender = hostel.hostel_gender where student_details.stud_id =" & cmbstud.SelectedValue.ToString & " ", sqlcont.Conn)
Dim datreadr5 As SqlDataReader = sqcm5.ExecuteReader
Dim dt5 As New DataTable
Dim n As Integer
For n = 0 To dt5.Rows.Count - 1
    datreadr5.Read()
Next
dt5.Load(datreadr5)
cmbhostel.ValueMember = "hostel_id" 
'asign value & display member b4 datasource to avoid errors
cmbhostel.DisplayMember = "hostel_name"
cmbhostel.DataSource = dt5
```

There are some similar questions: [ComboBox has its old value after Clear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306719/combobox-has-its-old-value-after-clear/24387051#24387051); however, they don't address my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing this did the trick:

```
Dim b As New BindingSource()
b.DataSource = dat
cmbstud.DataSource = b
b.ResetBindings(False)
```

Comment: 7 more hours @pixelmeow and I will be able to thanks